# GAS : send a reminder Email only once per person

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, reminders

I'm new on Google Apps Script and I've written a script to have a group task list in a Google Spreadsheet and automatically send people reminders if their task is due today.

The script is working fine, but I would like to improve it because in my script, if I have 3 tasks due today, I will receive 3 different emails. Is there a way I can send only 1 email per person with a recap of all the due tasks they have for today ?

I've looked for a while but can't find anything.

Thanks a lot !

[image: Spreadsheet pic]

```
function Reminders() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var newEmployee = sheet.getRange("C1").getValue();
  var sheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  var EMAIL_SENT = "OUI"

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(7, 200, 1, 12) // (sart Row, N° of Rows, Start Column, n° of Columns)
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[4]; // We look for email adress on colum 5
    if (emailAddress == "") continue;

    var subject = "Reminder - you have a task due today for " + newEmployee;
    var message = row[2];
    var joursrestants = row[7]; // We look for days left before task deadline in column 8
    var statut = row[9]; // We look for task statut in colum 9


    if (joursrestants == "0" && statut == "A FAIRE") { // if days left before task = 0 AND status = "A FAIRE" :

      // A. We send a reminder Email
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
          name: 'Rappel automatique',
          replyTo: 'no-reply@socomore.com',
      });

      // B. We write in colum 10 that a reminder has been sent
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 9).setValue(EMAIL_SENT)
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could do it.

To make the email contain summary information create a string inside a loop that adds to itself

```
    message= row[2] + message;
```

You could sort the spreadsheet by name, put MailApp inside an if statement that checks to see if the next line has a different name, if it does send email.

If you don't want to sort by name, you could loop through an array of all the possible names instead.